# Getting specific rows from recordset

Tags: mysql, sql, large-data-volumes

I have a big database result set and I want get specific rows from them with 1 Query:

1., 60.

and 61.,120.

and 121.,180.

... and every 60th and 61st record until I have all, the complete result needs to be provided by 1 Query.

Any idea how I can do that?

The LIMIT/OFFSET is not what I'm looking for, as I would need to repeat it many times.

Comment: Try to use LIMIT clause.

Comment: "The LIMIT/OFFSET is not what I'm looking for, as I would need to repeat it many times. " I don't understand why this is an issue? By definition you want to do multiple queries rather than one big one.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I wan't execute 1 Query and get all the results.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Those are specific rows, not ranges?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: correctly that are specific rows that I get by another query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an article that uses a single select statement to do this.  The statement itself is more complex, but certainly not cryptic by any means.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        @row := @row +1 AS rownum, noun
    FROM (
        SELECT @row :=0) r, nouns
    ) ranked
WHERE rownum %4 =1
```

[Here is the article.](http://www.webveteran.com/blog/index.php/web-coding/mysql/mysql-select-every-nth-record/)

Comment: Correct, but don't forget to: (a) `ORDER` the results, because a table has no inherent ordering so this query is currently broken; (b) update the `WHERE` clause for this specific question.

Comment: Thank you, that works. It takes time but it deliver what I ask for :)

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
WHERE id % 60 IN ('0','1')
```

*untested!

Comment: I don't have a usable counter like Autonum-ID in the existing result set. I must use the rows from my result set.

Comment: How do you know that he has an ordered `id` field?

Comment: Apologies, I assumed there would be one. Can one be `SELECT`ed out and then have this where applied?

Comment: I see that's exactly what the above question does.